# error: incompatible types: List<RNCMaskedView Manager> cannot be converted to List<View Manager> return Arrays.asList(

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

It's a react native app, since upgrade is unable to build, android studio throws this error.

````
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext    reactApplicationContext) {
      return Arrays.asList(
            new RNCMaskedViewManager()
      );
  }```
````

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but you are returning a list of RNCMaskedViewManager from a function that should return a list of ViewManager

Comment: yeah, but it's not something I have written. this is in build.gradle file.

Comment: are you sure? that looks like Java not Groovy